# Precompile assets with same digest on different hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Is it possible to compile assets on different hosts (traffic routing) with the same digest?

For example, if my Rails 3.2 app is deployed to 2 different hosts host1 and host2, I want to have `application.css` on both host1 and host2 with the same digest `application-34a9sadas1238023a8.css`

Answer (score 1):

The digest is going to be the same for each host because it is based on the content of the file.

If you are deploying to multiple hosts, the assets will get precompiled on both during deployment.

If you want to avoid this because of the time it takes, there is a way to compile locally and commit, and still have development mode work as expected. It is [here](http://richardhulse.blogspot.co.nz/2012/03/rails-how-to-compile-and-commit-assets.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just wonder whether there's a way to override the digest scheme to make it the same for multiple hosts?

Comment: The asset digest is meant to be the md5 hash of the generated file. Because the file should be identical on each host it is generated for, then the md5 hash (and therefore the digest) of each file will be the same.