# Sprocket: precompiled assets fingerprint inconsistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Our Rails 3.2 application uses 4 different hosts as CDN. Upon deployment, we have a task that run assets:precompile on these 4 boxes. The problem we're facing is that the assets that are compiled have different fingerprints/digests. My understanding is that the fingerprints/digests are generated from the content of our assets file so they should be the same across different boxes. Does anyone know what the cause might be? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have dug around in the code and can't see why this is. They should be the same.

If you are deploying to 4 hosts you might want to consider precompiling locally - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692348/rails-3-2-precompile-assets-with-same-digest-on-different-hosts) for details - as it is a lot faster.